# Visual Studio Code debugger for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

I have this setting file at Visual Studio Code launch.json:

```
"name": "Django",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"stopOnEntry": true,
"pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
"args": [
    "runserver",
    "--noreload",
    "--nothreading"
],
"env": {},
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
"debugOptions": [
    "RedirectOutput",
    "Django"
]
```

When I click on Debug --> Start Debugging, it auto generates the following syntax which is different from my setting file above:

C:\Users\HP\Work\ABC>cd C:\Users\HP\Work\ABC && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:\Users\HP\Work\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\HP.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.5.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py C:\Users\HP\Work\ABC 65530 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 **RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput,DjangoDebugging** C:\Users\HP\Work\ABC/manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading
"

When executing the above debugger, it always return inconsistent error messages such as:

- RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
- raise Exception('failed to attach') Exception: failed to attach

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in my launch.json:

```
{
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload",
            "--nothreading"
        ],
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
```

Maybe you can try it out and it'll work!

Comment: Doesn't work, when I press start debugging, after trying to run it just stopped and goes back out to command terminal, look at the botttom right of this image https://imgur.com/a/cNYVTT0